# How to wrap a text in span cells in reportlab?

Tags: python, html, pdf, report, reportlab

I am using reportlab to create a report. I create a table which contains information of product code, product name, description, qty, unit price and total price. At the bottom of the table I span cells where I would like to write terms and conds and next to it I would like to add the sub-total and some taxes to compute the total of the quotation.

this is what I have tried:

```
def quotation_table() -> None:
    '''
    This function builds a dynamic quotation table.
    '''
    
    # set the current style for numbers in Venezuela 
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'es_ES.UTF-8')

    # set size and margins for the pdf file
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
        'simple_table.pdf',
        pagesize = letter,
        rightMargin = cm,
        leftMargin = cm,
        topMargin = cm,
        bottomMargin = cm,
        showBoundary = True
    )

    # set the normal style sheet for Paragraph flowables
    pstyles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    normal_style = pstyles['Normal'].clone('new_normal_style')
    normal_style.fontName = 'Courier'
    normal_style.alignment = TA_JUSTIFY
    normal_style.fontSize = 8

    # set the span style sheet for Paragraph flowable
    pspan_style = pstyles['Normal'].clone('new_normal_style')
    pspan_style.alignment = TA_LEFT
    pspan_style.fontSize = 8
    pspan_style.fontName = 'Courier'
    pspan_style.wordWrap = True


    # instiantite an empty list to store flowables
    story = []

    # table header
    header = [
        '#', 
        'Code', 
        'Product Name', 
        'Description', 
        'Qty', 
        'U. Price', 
        'T. Price'
    ]

    # this is going to store all the data to display in the table
    data = [
        header
    ]

    # insert the values of the table
    stop = False
    n = 0
    total_per_item = []
    while not stop:
        row = []  # for every iteration, reset this list

        n += 1
        row.append(n)

        code = input('enter the product code: ')
        row.append(
            Paragraph(code, normal_style)
        )

        name = input('enter the product name: ')
        row.append(
            name
        )

        description = input('enter the product description: ')
        row.append(
            Paragraph(description, normal_style)
        )

        qty = int(input('enter the qty: '))
        row.append(
            locale.format_string('%.0f', qty, grouping = True) 
        )

        unit_price = float(input('enter the unit price: '))
        row.append(
            locale.format_string('%.2f', unit_price, grouping = True) 
        )

        total_price = qty * unit_price
        total_per_item.append(total_price)  # store the results in this list
        row.append(
            locale.format_string('%.2f', total_price, grouping = True)
        )

        data.append(row)  # append the row to the table
        
        q = input('want to continue inserting products? (y/n): ')

        if q == 'n':
            stop = True
    
    # sum the total per item to get the subtotal
    sub_total = sum(total_per_item)
    iva = sub_total * .16
    igt = False
    if igt:
        igt = sub_total * .3
        total = locale.format_string('%.2f', sub_total + iva + igt, grouping = True)
    else:
        total = sub_total + iva
        total = locale.format_string('%.2f', sub_total + iva, grouping = True)

    # add the terms & conds, subtotal, iva, igt and total
    span_text = 'Aquí está el texto que quiero que ocupe todas las celdas span.'
    span_paragraph = Paragraph(span_text, pspan_style)
    terms_conds = [
        span_text,  # here must be added terms & conds
        '', 
        '', 
        '', 
        '', 
        'Sub-Total:',
        locale.format_string('%.2f', sub_total, grouping = True)
    ]
    data.append(terms_conds)  # append terms & conds row to the table

    iva_cell = [
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        'IVA (16 %):',
        locale.format_string('%.2f', iva, grouping = True)
    ]
    data.append(iva_cell)  # append iva to the table

    # append igt to the table (if apply)
    if not igt:
        igt_cell = [
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            'IGT (3 %):',
            '-'
        ]
        data.append(igt_cell) 
    else:
        igt_cell = [
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            'IGT (3 %):',
            locale.format_string('%.2f', igt, grouping = True)
        ]
        data.append(igt_cell)

    total_cell = [
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        'Total:',
        total
    ]
    data.append(total_cell)  # append total to the table
    
    # customize the table style
    tstyle = [
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), '#46ACC2'),  # (begin_col, begin_row), (end_col, end_row)
        ('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Courier-Bold', 10),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'CENTRE'),
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, colors.black),
        ('BOX', (0, 1), (-1, -1),1, colors.black),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 1), (4, -1), 'CENTRE'),
        ('ALIGN', (5, 1), (6, -1), 'RIGHT'),
        ('FONT', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'Courier', 8),
        ('SPAN', (0, -1), (4, -1)),  # span cells in a table for terms & conds
        ('LINEABOVE', (0, -4), (-1, -4), 1, colors.black)  # add a horizontal line before terms & conds
    ] 

    # altenating background colors
    num_row = len(data)
    for i in range(1, num_row):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            tstyle.append(('BACKGROUND', (0, i), (-1, i), colors.beige))
        else:
            tstyle.append(('BACKGROUND', (0, i), (-1, i), colors.azure))

    # drawing the horizontal lines of the table
    num_col = len(header)
    for i in range(num_col - 1):
        if i >= 4:
            tstyle.append(('LINEAFTER', (i, 0), (i, -1), 1, colors.black))  # add a complete vertical line
        else: 
            tstyle.append(('LINEAFTER', (i, 0), (i, -5), 1, colors.black))  # add a vertical line until 5 rows above the end
    
    # set the table styles
    tblstyle = TableStyle(tstyle)

    # set the columns width of the table
    col_width = [cm, 2 * cm, 3.5 * cm, 6.43 * cm, 1.5 * cm, 2.6 * cm, 2.6 * cm]

    # instantiate the Table class
    tbl = Table(data, colWidths = col_width, spaceAfter = 0)
    tbl.setStyle(tblstyle)

    # 
    
    # append the table flowable to story
    story.append(tbl)

    # build the document
    doc.build(story)
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I can't find information about hot to wrap a text (could be a Paragraph) that fits the width of the span cells in a correct way! Reportlab forces the text to live inside the first column. Is there a way? or reportlab doesn't support this! Thanks